# Specific reasons to use |= instead of =

Tags: c, linux, arm

I am currently looking over some code in the Linux kernel (thermal management). In some places there is a return value used to signal errors, which is set to 0 at the beginning of the function. Then when calling a function which may fail it is set to the new value using `|=` instead of `=`. Here is an example:

```
int ti_bandgap_read_temperature(struct ti_bandgap *bgp, int id,
                int *temperature)
{
    u32 temp;
    int ret;

    ret = ti_bandgap_validate(bgp, id);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    spin_lock(&bgp->lock);
    temp = ti_bandgap_read_temp(bgp, id);
    spin_unlock(&bgp->lock);

    ret |= ti_bandgap_adc_to_mcelsius(bgp, temp, &temp);
    if (ret)
        return -EIO;

    *temperature = temp;

    return 0;
}
```

The definition of `ti_bandgap_validate` is:

```
/**
 * ti_bandgap_validate() - helper to check the sanity of a struct ti_bandgap
 * @bgp: struct ti_bandgap pointer
 * @id: bandgap sensor id
 *
 * Checks if the bandgap pointer is valid and if the sensor id is also
 * applicable.
 *
 * Return: 0 if no errors, -EINVAL for invalid @bgp pointer or -ERANGE if
 * @id cannot index @bgp sensors.
 */
static inline int ti_bandgap_validate(struct ti_bandgap *bgp, int id)
```

So, if my reasoning is correct, at the call to `ti_bandgap_adc_to_mcelsius()`, the value of `ret` must be `0` (otherwise the function would have exited already). So what is the reason for using `|=` here instead of `=`? Doing an "or" with a pattern of all zeros will just give back the normal pattern. Is this some kind of optimization for the usual case, i.e. that the function is returning no failure (i.e. return value `0`)? Or is there some other difference I am missing? This code is running on an ARM-architecture, so it might have to do something with specific optimizations for that platform.

Comment: Strikes me as good form: That way, someone reading the code doesn't need to look at surrounding context to be assured that under no circumstance will they be overwriting a nonzero error return.

Comment: Looks like it was some leftover or not desired. It was removed in a newer commit https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e34238bf98a2ad9deda9444d69903889eced0519#diff-a50a7076f4668c922ed31669c390eb17R836

Comment: This code will be slower on ARM, as the previous value has to be remembered instead of just using the return register. There is also no use her, as the function net even returns the value in the final `return`. I do not see this is more robust. As it has been removed according to @nnn's comment, it might be part of an abandoned error-handling concept.

Comment: Specific part from that commit's comment is `Avoid confusing |= on error values.`

Comment: @Charles Duffy: No, it is actually an extremely *bad form*. Firstly, from the abstract point of view, it is simply an error: it basically attempts to OR standard `E...` error constants, which is meaningless. Preserving a *meaningless* non-zero value is no better than losing it entirely. Secondly, from the specific point of view, it forces the reader of the code to search around and manually deduce the fact that `ret` is guaranteed to be zero at that point, thus making `|=` equivalent to `=`. It is never a good form to force the reader to make such unnecessary efforts.

Comment: @KeithThompson As Bugs Bunny might have said, "I knew I should have made that left turn at Albuquerque".  There is no Java parallel, except in some legacy straight-port code bases I have known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there is no reason to use `|=` however, if you are tracking a number of functions that might error, and return if they error as the return code, the pattern is

```
boolean error = false

error |= doFirstStep(...);
error |= doSecondStep(...);
error |= doThirdStep(...);

if (error) {
  printf("error occurred: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

It is a lesser used pattern in C, occasionally used in languages with some affinity with C.  In the C language, a great number of C library functions return an "error code" which is typically 0 on successful operation.

When using this pattern, the user relies on the return of zero as a success condition.  This means that the above-mentioned  `log_and_recover()` might pull the error message out of the error.h a static variable, as is common to the C `#include <error.h>` routines.

---- To continue in why this is often used on int fields ----

You also see this pattern with an `int` holding the error.

```
int error = 0; // or a variable that's defined to zero

error |= doFirstStep(...);
error |= doSecondStep(...);
error |= doThirdStep(...);

if (error != 0) {
  ... some error handling ...
}
```

When you see this, it is the same idea as above, but the developer combined two patterns.  The bit field pattern which is often used for packing configuration parameters is being leveraged to pack multiple kinds of errors.  Typically when this happens you can find a list of errors similar to

```
#define ERROR_NO_DISK  (1<<1);
#define ERROR_NO_NETWORK (1<<2);
#define ERROR_NO_SANITY (1<<3);
```

It isn't terribly sensible for most items to return multiple errors and handle them as one; but sometimes it is done when error suppression is important.  For example, if you fail transmit a message from a client to a host, odds are you could suppress the various "failure to open a socket", "failure to write to socket", "failure to copy to buffer", etc. failures into a generic "failure to send X".  At one level, the entire top level workflow failed, and if needed the details of why are still somewhat available.

Comment: With a genuine boolean variable it looks better, since it better conveys the intent to ignore the actual return codes. But in any case, ignoring actual return codes is something that belongs in sketch-quality code. In production-grade code  this wouldn't look good.

Comment: How is Java relevant?

Comment: @AnT I agree it looks better with a boolean variable, but those were in short supply in legacy C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Scrubbed of Java references.  Honestly, I don't know how I read the above and mentally crammed it into an object-oriented mindset ;)

Comment: @Edwin Buck: If the standard `E...` codes followed the "the bit field pattern" described in the second part of your post, then the use of `|=` would indeed be more than justified. Morover, I would insist on using `|=` as a matter of good programming practice even when it is known that `ret` is zero. However, standard `E...` codes don't conform to "the bit field pattern", which is why the main premise of second part of your answer is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @AnT That's why I mentioned "You also see the pattern".  Of course using error codes as bit fields are not standard, but such a use might justify the `|=` under the case that they are used.  And if they are used, while it is a bit of a stretch and not (in my opinion) the best way to go about it, I provided the (shaky) justification.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use `|=` in this context.  As you stated, `ret` must be 0 when this line is reached, otherwise it would have returned earlier.  It also introduces an additional operation which is unnecessary.

As was mentioned in the comments, this operator was in fact changed to `=` in [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e34238bf98a2ad9deda9444d69903889eced0519#diff-a50a7076f4668c922ed31669c390eb17R836).  The commit comment states:

> Avoid confusing |= on error values.